# major issues keep popping up in the code

Tags: php, database, performance, object

i got a problem going through the index of a database - I get this error:

***Fatal error: Call to a member function error() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ooplr\index.php on line 5***

```
<?

php
require_once "core/init.php";
$users = DB::getInstance()->get('users',array('username','=','alex'));

if($users->error()){ ***<--- ERROR MESSAGE ON THIS LINE!!!***
    echo  'No user';
} else {
    echo 'OK!';
}
```

The error message is on line #5. How can i turn $users into an object?

the get method works just fine - TESTED IT!

so what seems to be the issue amigos?

i just did a var_dump($users) and it is printing bool(false)...why's that?

Comment: I'm guessing thet `get()` method doesnt return an object. You could try making two lines of it, the instance, and the `$users->get()`, or check wether your `get` method fails.

Comment: `$users` is probably null

Comment: Do a `var_dump($users);` and report what it prints out.

Comment: i just did a var_dump($users); and it is printing bool(false)!

Comment: why is it printing false if i do have a username called alex in the database? do u need a printout of the database phpmyadmin backend?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: what do u mean? i'm using XAMPP...raw code that is...what frame work should i be using?

Comment: Did you write the DB class yourself?

Comment: how did you test `get()` method to know it's working, when it's returning false

Comment: partially by myself... partly with some help... ok so if its returning false,what do u want me to do?

Comment: the get() method shows no error during execution...that's how i figured out it is probably working...or is my methodology wrong?

Comment: the database has a value but why is it reading null?

Comment: yoo hoo? anyone willing to help out here?

Comment: Patience is a virtue and more so when advice is free and better still most of us don't live in cyberspace constantly, we like the game and appreciate helping others. It seems that if `get` can't find what it needs it returns `false`, this is a common thing to do in php. There will be no `php error` for `get()` unless you call the method incorrectly, basically an `error` is (most times) caused by syntax or reference issues. As far as I can see `get()` is not finding what you want, so it `return false`. Verify that you call `get` correctly, or even post a link to the `DB` class you're using.

Comment: here's the link to what i'm using - http://pastebin.com/LTE2tPye

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LTE2tPye - link to the DB class that i'm using gwillie & co.

Comment: anybody can help out with this???

Comment: To me this seems like homework, it seems to me that the `DB` class is dodgy, it seems to me that it's not meant to work. Where did you get the `DB` class from. Is this an exercise for college/school?

Comment: sorta gwillie...can u figure this out please? i'm confused!

Comment: gwillie...this is actually for work...i need to get this job done ASAP! can u help out please?!?

Comment: can NO ONE out there not help me out?!?

Comment: I'm currently checking out your DB class, have any of you modified it? or are you using an exact copy?

Comment: i'm using the exact copy

Comment: ok...but now that i fixed the issue...it says no user...why's that?

Answer (score 0):

#### Your revised DB class

Added a bunch of methods to be removed once we find the culprit

```
<?php
class DB{
  const OP_EQUALS  = 0;
  const OP_M_THAN  = 1;
  const OP_L_THAN  = 2;
  const OP_ME_THAN = 3;
  const OP_LE_THAN = 4;
  /**
   * Singleton pattern
   * @var PDO object
   */
  private static $instance = null;
  /**
   * @var PDO object
   */
  private $pdo;
  /**
   * prepared statements
   * @var PDOStatement object
   */
  private $query;
  /**
   * This class is incomplete, this is important but neglected, time to change that...
   * @var PDOStatement object
   */
  private $results;
  /**
   * Holds the result of calling stmt->rowCount() for the current query
   * @var integer the behaviour of this is not guaranteed
   */
  private $count = 0;
  private function __construct(){
    try {
      $host = Config::get('mysql/host');
      $data = Config::get('mysql/db');
      $user = Config::get('mysql/username');
      $pass = Config::get('mysql/password');
      $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$data;
      $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
      $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      // not for production
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
  public static function getInstance(){
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new DB;
    return self::$instance;
  }
  /**
   * This is a blanket fetch all, seems ok
   * @param string $q
   * @param array $params
   * @return DB
   */
  public function query($q, array $params=array()) {
    $this->count = null;
    $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($q);
    $this->query->execute($params);
    $this->results = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'stdClass');
    $this->count = $this->query->rowCount();
    return $this;
  }
  /**
   * This is a cute function, but I do not recomend it's use
   * @param string $action
   * @param string $table
   * @param array $where
   * @return DB
   */
  private function action($action, $table, array $where=array()){
    static $operators = array('=','>','<','>=','<=');
    if (count($where)===3) {
      list($op1,$operator,$op2) = $where;
      if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
        $q = $action.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$op1.' '.$operator.' ?';
        return $this->query($q,$operators);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  /**
   * This abstraction seems convenient but it will become a nightmare later on
   * @param string $table
   * @param array $where
   * @return DB
   */
  public function get($table, array $where=array(1,0,1)){
    return $this->action('SELECT *',$table,$where);
  }
  /**
   * This abstraction seems convenient but it will become a nightmare later on
   * @param string $table
   * @param array $where
   * @return DB
   */
  public function delete($table, array $where=array(1,0,1)){
    return $this->action('DELETE',$table,$where);
  }
  public function getResultSet(){
    return $this->results;
  }
  /*
   * start debugging functions
   */

  /**
   * Returns a prepared statement
   * @param string $q
   * @return PDOStatement
   */
  public function debug_statement($q) {
    return $this->pdo->prepare($q);
  }
  /**
   * Directly executes a statement
   * @param string $q
   * @param int $fetch_options
   * @return PDOStatement
   */
  public function debug_query($q, $fetch_options=PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    return $this->pdo->query($q,$fetch_options);
  }
  /**
   * Get metadata from table
   * @param string $table
   * @return string
   */
  public function describe_table($table) {
    $stmt = $this->debug_query('DESC '.$table);
    return '<pre>'.print_r($stmt->fetchAll(),1).'</pre>';
  }
  /**
   * Get contents from table
   * @param string $table
   * @return string
   */
  public function dump_table($table) {
    $stmt = $this->debug_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    return '<pre>'.print_r($stmt->fetchAll(),1).'</pre>';
  }
}
```

#### a new debugging script

I hope this does not turn up empty, or I'll be very sad

```
// debugging information
// let's use a blanket statement to get all rows in the database
$db = DB::getInstance();
echo 'Currently debugging!'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Get a clear look at our `Users` table: '.$db->describe_table('users');
echo 'Dump all rows: '.$db->dump_table('users');
```

Use this DB class and then run the script. gimme some feedback on what you see

Comment: i still got an issue saying - Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ooplr\index.php on line 5

Comment: ok hanzo...i fixed it..but now i get "No User!" printed out when i have the user in the database...what could be wrong?

Comment: sorry I've been out. I'll take another shot at it and see. I'll be adding some debugging info to see what we get

Comment: I have a feeling the DB code you are using is incomplete. The code is missing some crucial `return` statements or some simple `get`ters. I hope you can modify your DB file, I'll edit my answer to include some changes to it and add some debugging info.

Comment: here's what i got hanzo - NO ROWS!!!!


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ooplr\index.php on line 11
No user

Comment: then this confirms that there's a problem in the database. You either have no rows, or you are connected to some empty database, or something. Now that we know that you have access to your database class, I'm going to try and post a revised edition to it. On your side, you'll have to check if your connection to the database is correct, and that the tables are full. This will take me a while so please be patient

Comment: alrite hanzo - here's the site that i picked this up from - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaBWDOBFxDc

Comment: a youtube video on OOP PHP programming!

Comment: Good to know you're learning, remember that the important things are the concepts behind OOP: it helps you write code that is easier to organize and maintain. I left you a new DB class, you can put it into your project and rename it whatever you like. Test your database with it and good luck on your endeavours